# How to make a user defined program for sorting strings?

Tags: c, sorting

The following is my code. I'm trying to make sort command manually. I am sorting strings. But I am not getting the desired output. So please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    char temp[10][5];
    char a[10][5]={"abc","xyz","pqrs","abcde","wxy"
                    "cd","lmnop","lmnkq","jkl","ghij"};
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        while(a[i][j]==a[i+1][j])
            j++;
        if(a[i][j]>a[i+1][j])
        {
            temp[i][j]= a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i+1][j];
            a[i+1][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your sorting problem: You have stores some strings of length 5 in a buffer of length 5; you'll have to provide an extra char to store the terminating null char, otherwise you can't properly print the strings. You also loop up to `i == 9` and then access `a[i + 1]`, which is out of `a`'s  bounds.

Comment: @MOehm: The IDEONE compiler suggests the strings are truncated to five characters so this may be OK, but probably not what was expected. This is a 2-dimensional array of characters, which is different to a 1-dimensional array of pointers to strings. There is no implicit nul-terminator.

Comment: @Skizz: The code is not illegal per se, but try printing such a string with `printf("%s", ...)` or calling any `strxxx` function on it.

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare c strings with ==, > and <

```
char a[5] = "abc";
char b[5] = "abc";
```

try this code and see that the condition will evaluate to false

```
if(a == b)
    printf("they are different");
```

When you do that you are comparing the address of them...

use function strcmp from string.h

```
if(strcmp(a, b) == 0)
    printf("they are equal");
```

you can't use = to assign either, use strcpy, also from string.h

Comment: he compares char values, so this is not the problem

Comment: oh, yea my bad...

but still, using the libraries is easier and faster, and good practice

Comment: The OP's not even using pointers, just characters. I think this person needs to take a step back and work on some of the fundamentals of computing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here:

- Some of your character strings are 5 characters long and will only fit into `char[5]` if the terminating null character is omitted. Printing such strings will print the following string, too, because the memory layout is contiguous. Also note that you initialise your array with only 9 strings, because the concatenation of the string literals `"wxy" "cd"` is the same as the single string  `"wxycd"`.
- When you swap strings, you must swap all the strings' characters, though you can skip equal heads.
- You implement bubble sort, but make only one pass of changing adjacent strings. That is not enough to sort your array; you must pass it repeatedly until all strings are sorted.
- You pass through all elements 0 to 9, but then access `a[i + 1]`,which is 10 and therefore out of bounds if `i == 9`. You can either adjust the right bound or you can start with `i = 1` and then address `a[i - 1]`.

So, here's a version that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int done = 0;       /* mark whether we are done */
    char a[10][6] = {
        "abc", "xyz", "pqrs", "abcde", "wxy",
            "cd", "lmnop", "lmnkq", "jkl", "ghij"
    };

    while (!done) {
        done = 1;       /* assume that we're done */

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            j = 0;
            while (a[i][j] == a[i + 1][j]) j++;
            if (a[i][j] > a[i + 1][j]) {
                while (j < 6) {
                    int temp = a[i][j];

                    a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j];
                    a[i + 1][j] = temp;
                    j++;
                }
                done = 0;   /* we've swapped strings, so we need to do more */
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code still is a bit awkward, because it tries to do everything in one big block and it works with static array bounds and buffer sizes. A better sort would just swap pointers to the strings.

Comment: is there a reason why you declare temp as an int to hold an char?

Comment: Thanks @M Oehm its really ossam code and it really works.But can u explain                                                              1.how a temp variable that is integer type can store char array?                                                                2. And why to use done flag?Is there any other alternate instead of using done flag in while loop?

Comment: @Manül: No, except habit, perhaps: Char literals like `'x'` are of type `int` and `getchar` also returns an `int`. But you're right, it should probably be a `char`.

Comment: @Muskaan: The `int` variable only holds one char; it is inside a loop that copies all characters. After one pass of bubble sort, you can be sure that the last item is in its correct place; it has "bubbled up" to the end. So you could have nine loops over a decreasing range until you know that your array is sorted. The check whether the sorting has been `done` is a frequent optimisation to bubble sort. (Not that it optimises much.)

Comment: Ohhkkk @M Oehm....But Any alternate of done flag?means anything else that can be written to check whether sorting is done or not?

Comment: Nothing wrong.I completely agree for the use of done flag.but can we write while(1)?I just want to know.Btw thanks for your immense help to explain me my mistake in my code and to make me understand it so well

Comment: @Muskaan: Of course, you can write a infinite loop with `while (1)` or `for (;;)` and then `break` out of it when you are done. It's just another implementation of the same logic.